# Show that the following metric is complete on $L_1(X,Y)$

Tags: banach-spaces, descriptive-set-theory, metrizability

I am working through the exercises of Kechris' [Classical Descriptive Set Theory](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/558212.Classical_Descriptive_Set_Theory?ac=1&from_search=true&qid=VkgXxV8DAx&rank=1) for personal edification. I've solved Exercise 3.5, but the proof was two pages. Did I miss a more straightforward method (either a "ground-up" approach, or one where the proof follows straightforwardly from a larger result)?

> **(3.5)** Show that the following is a complete compatible metric for the strong topology on $L_1(X,Y)$:
> $$d(S,T) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n-1} \|(S-T)(x_n)\|$$
> where $\{x_n\}$ is a dense sequence in the unit ball of $X$.

Above, $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces and $L_1(X,Y)$ is defined as the space of bounded linear operators $X\to Y$ with norm $\leq 1$, that is, the unit ball in $L(X,Y)$.  The strong topology is defined as the topology on $L(X,Y)$ generated by sets of the form
$$V_{y_1,\ldots,y_m;\varepsilon;T}:=\{S\in L(X,Y):\|Sy_1-Ty_1\|<\varepsilon,\ldots,\|Sy_m-Ty_m\|<\varepsilon\}$$
for $y_1,\ldots,y_m\in X$, $\varepsilon >0$, $T\in L(X,Y)$.

---

Here is a summary of my proof:

1. Let $\{S_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a Cauchy sequence in the metric $d$.
2. Show that $S_k$ converges pointwise on $\{x_n\}$ to a function $S:\{x_n\}\to Y$.
3. Show that $S$ is Lipschitz continuous with constant $1$.
4. Extend $S$ by continuity to the unit ball in $X$, then linearly to all of $X$, and show that the resulting function is in $L_1(X,Y)$.
5. Show that $S_k \to S$ in the $d$ metric (hence $d$ is complete).
6. Given a basis set in the strong topology, show that a $d$-open ball can fit inside it.
7. Given a $d$-open ball, show that a strong topology basis set can fit inside it.

(I can also post the proof as an answer here if it's useful).

Comment: Is there any particular step of your proof that seemed longer than it needs to be? My first inclination would be to show that the two topologies are the same by showing that they have the same convergent nets, rather than doing steps 6 and 7. But if your steps 6,7 are already short, that doesn't help much.

Comment: Steps 6,7 don't take too long, though I like the nets approach.  The finicky part seemed to be showing $S\in L_1(X,Y)$, and $S_k\to S$ in the $d$-metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a $d$-Cauchy $(S_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ and, as you have already done, show that $\lim_k S_kx_n$ exists for all $n=0,1,2,\ldots$.

Let $(M,d)$, $(N,\rho)$ be metric spaces with $(N,\rho)$ complete and let $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be $1$-Lipschitz functions which converge pointwise on a dense subset $A$ of $M$. Fix $\epsilon>0$, $x\in M$, and $y\in A$ such that $d(x,y)<\epsilon$. Then \begin{align*} \underset{k,l}{\lim\sup}\rho(f_k(x),f_l(x)) & \leqslant \underset{k,l}{\lim\sup}\text{ }\rho(f_k(x),f_k(y))+\rho(f_k(y),f_l(y))+\rho(f_l(y),f_l(x)) \\ & = \underset{k,l}{\lim\sup}\text{ }\rho(f_k(x),f_k(y))+\rho(f_l(y),f_l(x)) \leqslant 2\epsilon.\end{align*} First inequality is triangle inequality, second is because the functions converge at $y\in A$, and the last is because $f_k,f_l$ are $1$-Lipschitz and $d(x,y)<\epsilon$. This shows that $(f_k(x))_{k=1}^\infty$ is Cauchy, and therefore convergent in $N$ by completeness. Therefore $(f_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ is pointwise convergent on all of $M$.

Apply this with $f_k=S_k$, $A=\text{span}\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, $M=X$, and $N=Y$. We note that $\lim_k S_k\sum_{x\in F}a_xx=\sum_{x\in F}a_x\lim_k S_kx$ for any linear combination $\sum_{x\in F}a_xx$ of members $F$ of $\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, so that pointwise convergence on $\{x_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ and linearity give convergence on the entire span.

Then define $Sx=\lim_k S_kx$. Note that the pointwise limit of $1$-Lipschitz functions is $1$-Lipschitz (true on general metric spaces) and the limit of linear operators is linear. For the first fact, $\|Sx-Sy\|=\lim_k \|S_kx-S_ky\|\leqslant \|x-y\|$. For the second, $$S(ax+by)=\lim_k S_k(ax+by)=a\lim_k S_kx+b\lim_k S_ky=aSx+bSy.$$ So $S\in L_1(X,Y)$.

Then I would do 6 and 7 (or its equivalent with nets) without using completeness of $d$. Then we get that $\lim_k d(S,S_k)=0$ for free, because this is the same as saying $S_k\to S$ pointwise, which we already know it does by the preceding paragraphs